# Executar método pelo JSF automaticamente

Tags: java, jsf, restful

Tenho um JSF com um p:panelGrid com colunas que juntas formam uma tela que chamamos de telemetria (tela grande com vários informações passando em tempo real), em cada coluna adicionei um método no qual passei um ID como parâmetro para pesquisa no banco e então é retornado o valor. Algumas infomações são muito grandes, então usei o para os valores andarem nas celulas das colunas. Essa tela precisa se atualizar constantemente, porém não consegui configurar o restful corretamente para me ajudar, então usei o p:poll do primefaces para atualizar o painel a cada 10 segundos, porém, dessa forma não está sendo muito útil. Precisava de alguma maneira de atualizar as informações de cada célular automaticamente.

Abaixo tem um pedaço do painel com o metodo:

```
<p:column styleClass=" columnDark " >
    <marquee>#{telemetriaManagedBean.getTags("AFM1_Status")}</marquee>
 </p:column>
<p:column styleClass=" columnDark " >
    <marquee>#{telemetriaManagedBean.getTags("AFM2_Status")}</marquee>
</p:column>
```

---

O p:poll é a solução atual:

```
<p:poll interval="10" update="panelTelemetria" immediate="true" listener="#{telemetriaManagedBean.resetPage()}" />
```

Procuro outra solução, essa tela ficara aberta em uma TV para demais usuários enquanto puder.

Comment: Poste o seu `p:poll`

Comment: poste mais informações para que possamos lhe ajudar

Comment: Eu preciso atualizar as informações da tela de acordo com as informações do banco de dados. Caso o valor de **AFM1_Status** for alterada,o jsf deve perceber e alterar esse valor no panelGrid.